# How do you select a file after opening a file dialog box with a batch script?

Tags: file, batch-file, select, import, autocad

The computers lab at my university does a system restart every night and clears all local file information. I use AutoCAD a lot and have been able to save my custom settings, but everytime I log in I have to open AutoCAD, close AutoCAD, import my settings, then reopen AutoCAD.

I was hoping to write a Batch or vbscript to automate this, but I am still very new to programming.

My current issue is I have a Batch file to open the import settings file dialogbox, but once that it open, how do I program it to go to the file location where my settings are saved as zip file.

What I have looks like this:

```
Start "" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\AutoCAD 
2018 - English\Migrate Custom Settings\Import AutoCAD 2018 Settings.lnk"
```

This opens a dialog box for me to select my customs settings file and I wont it to automatically do that in the script.

Comment: Surely the restart doesn't delete profiles etc. Have you considered [using a shortcut](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Start-AutoCAD-with-different-profiles.html) for this task?

Comment: what happens if you open `cmd` `cd` to the dir where autocad is located and do `acad.exe /?` .. surely it should have cmdline siwtches like `/w` to load a workspace etc?

Comment: Take a look at, [this page](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Push-custom-settings-to-the-registry-at-startup-through-an-arg-profile.html), for information on using an `.arg` file.